# How to match any of the two values from database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some text in `database1` and `database2` tables that must match `can_do($can, $user_id)` function and if it doesn't match it will return `false`.

The problem is it checks both tables and returns `false` when `database1` is set but `database2` is not set. I need it to return `true` if `database1` is set even if the `database2` is not set and vice versa. How can I achieve that?

Here is the code:

```
   function can_do(  $can, $user_id ) {
        if ( $can ) {
            $test1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'database1', true );
            $test2 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'database2', true );
            $function = get_functionvalue();

            if($test1 != $function OR $test2 != $function ) {
                $can = false;
            }
        }
        return $can;
    }

    add_filter( 'custom_wordpress_can_do', 'can_do', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `OR` with `AND`, which will return false when both not matches.

`if($test1 != $function && $test2 != $function )`